# How to Read a word document in asp.net in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, docx, doc

> can any one help me to find out the solution to show/Read the word
>   documents in asp.net mvc any example or any suitable links. searched a lot on internet for suitable
>   article but did not find any thing helpful. i have implemented the
>   download functionality of the document. but can not able to read or
>   preview the documents.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use the Office Web Viewer provided as a service from Microsoft .**

What is the [Office Web Viewer](http://officewebviewer.com/)?

It’s a service that creates Office Web Viewer links.  Office Web Viewer links open Word, PowerPoint or Excel files in the browser that would otherwise be downloaded. You can easily turn a download link into an Office Web Viewer link to use in your website or blog (e.g., recipes, photo slide show, a menu, or a budget template).

[Office Web Viewer: View Office documents in a browser](http://blogs.office.com/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/)

Some benefits of the Office Web Viewer include:

- You don’t need to convert Office files for the web (e.g., PDF, HTML).
- Anyone can view Office files from your website or blog, even if they
  don’t have Office.
- It keeps eyes on your website or blog, because readers don’t need to
  download the file and they stay in the browser.
- One link will work for computers, tablets, and mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate `.docx` files (as well as `.xlsx`, `.pptx`, etc.) you would use [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) (also available as installer from Microsoft download centre).

The [PowerTools for Open XML](https://powertools.codeplex.com/), which greatly simplifies working with `Open XML SDK`, contains functionality for

`High-fidelity conversion of DOCX to HTML/CSS using HtmlConverter.cs`

I've only used this SDK and Powertools to manipulate Word documents, so could not say much about conversion to HTML/CSS. But this could be one of your options for previewing Word documents, although it is a complicated way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MVC viewer in Gnostice XtremeDocumentStudio .NET.

[ASP.NET MVC document viewer using ASPX and Razor engines.](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=290&t=A_multi_format_ASP_NET_MVC_viewer_for_DOCX_DOC_PDF_BMP_PNG_TIFF_EMF_WMF)

**DISCLAIMER: I work for this company.**